# Usar imagen como fondo de un <div> y que se vea tamaño completo Zurb Foundation

Tags: html, css, foundation

Buenas tardes.
Estoy usando el framework Zurb Foundation y necesito que un grid-block tenga como fondo una imagen. Estoy usando la propiedad Background-image pero al ser el div mas pequeño que la imagen, esta no se ve de tamaño completo.

Como necesito que se vea:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se ve:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi html:

```
<div class="grid-block" style="background-image: url('/assets/img/fondo-cabecera.jpg'); width: 100; height: 100; ">
```

Comment: Te faltan las unidades en el ancho y alto.

Comment: Sería mejor que evitaras usar estlos en línea como estás haciendo. Mejor usa una hoja de estilos aparte,o bien, crea la etiqueta `style` en el `head` de tu HTML. Y, por favor @ZyMonogatari, marca alguna de las respuestas de abajo como válida si ayudó a resolver tu problema...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podría funcionar si a la propiedad `height`le das un valor de `100vh`, esto hará que tu contenedor ocupe el 100% de la altura de la ventana del navegador. Adicionalmente te recomiendo añadirle la propiedad `min-height` con un valor igual o mayor a la altura del contenido para que siempre se visualice correctamente.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta darle al div que va a contener el background, un width 100%, y un height 100vh (viewport height).

```
<div class="grid-block" style="background-image: url('/assets/img/fondo-cabecera.jpg'); width: 100%; height: 100vh; ">
```

Answer (score 1):

Buenas:
Puedes probar de la siguiente manera

```
.claseDelDiv{background-image: url("/la/url/de/la/imagen.png");background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: cover;}
```

Tambien podrias probar el background-size: 100%, solo que si tu imagen es muy pequeña para el contenedor, la misma se estirara y se deformara mucho.
Lo bueno del "cover" es que se adapta bien en el responsive.
Espero te ayude.

Saludos.